# Is hashing (MD5 or SHA1) new Facebook API 2's app-scoped IDs safe?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, hash

After Facebook introduced the new Facebook API v2, it seems the new app-scoped IDs are simply (not very short) strings.
A bit more about this:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading

How safe do you think is to hash those IDs using MD5 or SHA1 and what are the chances for collisions?